# Print error in while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Helli I'm a beginner programmer and I'm getting a print syntax error and I don't know why....

```
def Input_Q_bounds (lower,upper):
    delta_x = .1

    #since there are 100 iterations
    J=np.zeros(101)
    for i in range(101) :
        Q=(i*delta_x)+(delta_x/2)
        if lower <=(Q_i)<= upper :
            Q_i =1
        else :
            Q_i=0
        #now fill the matrix
        J[i]=(Q+(9.5*(J[i-1])))/10.5

        while (i==1):
            J_analytical = Q*(np.exp(upper-10)+(np.exp(lower-10))
            print(J_analytical)
                break
```

Here's the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-135-25106d5ec500>", line 19
print(J_analytical)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You forgot to close a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line before

```
print(J_analytical)
```

the brackets do not match!

```
J_analytical = Q*(np.exp(upper-10)+(np.exp(lower-10))
                                                     ^

# change it to:
J_analytical = Q*(np.exp(upper-10)+(np.exp(lower-10)))
                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses in the line above are not balanced - you have four open parens and only three closing parens.